# Reusing session variables across multiple pages

Tags: php, mysql

I am passing the following variables from a query through a link:

```
 <a href="middle.php?name=<?php echo $name;  ?>&id=<?php echo $id1;  ?>&rowid=<?php echo $rowid;  ?>&record=<?php echo $record;  ?>">
```

The variables are being passed to this page:

```
session_start();

//$id = ($_GET['id']);
if (isset($_GET["record"])) {
    $_SESSION["record"] = $_GET["record"];
}
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $_SESSION["id"] = $_GET["id"];
}
if (isset($_GET["rowid"])) {
    $_SESSION["rowid"] = $_GET["rowid"];
}
if (isset($_GET["name"])) {
    $_SESSION["name"] = $_GET["name"];
}
if (isset($_GET["store"])) {
    $_SESSION["store"] = $_GET["store"];
}
```

and then users are redirected to this page where Im trying to use the assign the session variables to variables in the page like this:

```
session_start();

$id = $_SESSION[id];

$rowid = $_SESSION[rowid];

$name = $_SESSION[name];

$record = $_SESSION[record];
```

The variables arent accessible as I need them to be on this page. Am I missing quotes? What is the best way to use the session variables again?

FYI they're mainly being used in other queries like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM mgap_orders WHERE mgap_ska_id = '" . $_SESSION['id'] . "' AND mgap_status = 0 GROUP BY mgap_ska_report_category LIMIT 5";
```

Comment: Yes, you should quote the array keys. PHP will polite assume you just forgot them and pretend they're there, but will issue warnings, and you CAN run into trouble if you have any `define()`'d constants of the same name. Check `session_id()` in all of the pages you're having trouble on. If the id changes, then you've got a session configuration problem and each page is getting a brand new/empty session.

Comment: You should sanitize / filter your variables as you add them to the session as they are user-provided. Using them later on like this will lead to sql injection problems. You should also initialize them so that you don't have to check everywhere whether they are set.

Comment: Also, I have ran into the problem before where sometimes php is set in register_globals to register session variables as globals.

So when you do $_SESSION["name"] = $_GET["name"]; the name, 'Aaron' or whatever, becomes assigned to $name and then you can not overwrite it with $name = $_SESSION['name'];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I missing quotes?

Yes.  You say you're accessing them like this:

```
$id = $_SESSION[id];
```

That should be this:

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```

But even more to the point, why do you need to use session here at all?  The way you describe the situation is:

1. User makes a request with query string values in the link.
2. In the response you forward the user to another page (presumably using the location header?).
3. On the last page the values need to be present.

If they're query string values, keep them as query string values in the redirect.  So where you may have something like this:

```
header('Location: somePage.php');
```

you can include the values:

```
header('Location: somePage.php?name=' . $name');
```

and so on for the remainder of the values, just like you do when building the original link for the page which performs the redirect.

Also, while you don't show your data access, you do show your query which appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.  Ultimately the values you're using are coming from user input (query string) so you shouldn't directly concatenate them into SQL queries.